# Ruby, pry: Can I add something to the command `pry example.rb` so pry automatically goes interactive when it finishes executing the script?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, read-eval-print-loop, pry, interactive-mode

Pry goes into interactive mode if it encounters an exception (eg if you just put an undefined variable 'x' at the end of the script).

(Also if, inside the script itself you `require 'pry'` and put `binding.pry` at the point you want to go interactive at.)

But I'm wondering: Is there's some kind of flag/option/argument thingy that I can add to the `pry example.rb` command when I enter it at the command prompt, so it will go interactive when it reaches the end of executing *any* `example.rb` script, regardless of what's inside? (Assuming no exceptions *before* the end, of course.)

*(This would obviously be especially useful for use with editors that you can run external programs from like Notepad++, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903709/how-do-i-setup-the-notepad-run-command-for-ruby/12904268#12904268) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903709/how-do-i-setup-the-notepad-run-command-for-ruby/12904268#12904268).)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, but file an [issue](http://github.com/pry/pry/issues) and i'll add it :)

Comment: Okay, sure. Should I copy [this pry problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211133/ruby-get-pry-to-display-characters-like-aoussaouss-utf-8-encoding-correctly) over to github too? :) (Did you already see it?)

Comment: There, posted [an issue for `pry -i example.rb` on github](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/911). Looks like a volunteer helper showed up in the first two minutes. ^^

Comment: Aaaaaand patch is merged. :)

Comment: @richo How does it work? I just `gem update pry`'d, but I can't seem to get any sort of `-i` flag to work...

Comment: It's on master, so not released, you would need to `git clone git://github.com/pry/pry.git; cd pry; gem build pry.gemspec; gem install pry-*.gem`